# Factory method: difference in assignment and strcpy_s

Tags: c++, string, factory, tchar

I have code that I am using to learn design patterns and C++ that has the `tchar` header, which I gather is a legacy header from Windows. I was thinking of switching to `std::string` but I don't know if I would be missing an important point in the inheritance or factory method by changing to the code shown later [**my modification**] and also not using `strcpy_s`.

Am I missing something important within the fundamentals of the factory design pattern or in C++? I am new to C++.

**As it is:**

```
class Product
{
protected:
    char _type[15];
public:
    Product()
    {
    }
    char *getType()
    {
        return _type;
    }
};
```

```
class ConcreteProduct : public Product
{
public:
    ConcreteProduct : Product()
    {
        strcpy_s(_type, "ConcreteProduct");
    }
};
```

**My modification**

```
class Product
{
protected:
    std::string _type;
public:
    Product()
    {
    }
    char *getType()
    {
        return _type;
    }
};
```

```
class ConcreteProduct : public Product
{
public:
    ConcreteProduct : Product()
    {
        std::string _type = "ConcreteProduct";
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `strcpy` in C++?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, it is in the tutorial I am following.

Comment: @heretoinfinity You may wish to use a more modern tutorial instead.

Comment: @gha.st, is my use of std::string valid though?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided sample code is not actually using `<tchar.h>` (your character type should be `_TCHAR` in that case), but rather the basic C (not C++) [string handling functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

The idea of replacing this with `std::string` is very much the right idea - and you may wish to throw out the tutorial you are using for attempting to teach you differently.

The code you attempted to create has a few problems though. First off, the `_type` member field is now a `std::string` that cannot be implicitly converted to a `char*`, so your definition of the `type` function will not compile. Since you are modifying the example anyway, you can just return a `const` reference to your member:

```
class Product {
protected:
    std::string _type;

    Product() = default;
    Product(Product const&) = default;
    Product& operator=(Product const&) = default;
    Product(Product &&) = default;
    Product& operator=(Product &&) = default;

    Product(std::string _type) : _type(std::move(_type)) { }

public:
    std::string const& getType() { return _type; }
};
```

Note that I also removed the erroneous `Coffee()` constructor (I assume that you intended to write `Product` here).

By writing `Product() = default;´, we instruct C++ to automatically generate an empty constructor. You may have noticed that this constructor is now`protected`- we do not want the user of your class to be able to create a`Product` directly. (This may be the wrong thing to do, depending on your application.)

I have done the same thing to the copy and move operators to prevent [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), which many aspiring C++ programmers that first dip their toes into inheritance stumble over.

Finally, there is a constructor `Product(std::string)` that will initialize the `_type` member.

In the next step, you can derive from `Product`:

```
class ConcreteProduct : public Product {
public:
    ConcreteProduct() : Product("ConcreteProduct") { }
    ConcreteProduct(ConcreteProduct const&) = default;
    ConcreteProduct& operator=(ConcreteProduct const&) = default;
    ConcreteProduct(ConcreteProduct &&) = default;
    ConcreteProduct& operator=(ConcreteProduct &&) = default;
};
```

Note that we are now making the copy and move constructors public and are able to use the constructor syntax to intialize the base `Product` directly.

[Full example](https://godbolt.org/z/b2vpMT)

Comment: you are right about the erroneous coffee. I edited my question.